# Backdrop remains from the bounding box after the modal is closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, img-area-select-jquery

I have been working on code to tag the images using [the `imgAreaSelect` jQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/imgareaselect/). For this I have a modal that popups when clicking the image and the modal holds the content to tag the image. This part works fine. The problem I face is when I close the modal, the bounding box which I drew over the image remains even after the modal is closed. I want to remove that modal backdrop and I don't know how to proceed.

I have attached the link for Jsfiddle below
 https://jsfiddle.net/Uviii/rb67myvn/2/

Html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
        <div class='dynamic_text' style='display:none;'></div>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="fashion.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="text_container">
        <br>
        <div class="img_text"></div>
        <div class="input_tag">
            <span class="right_sec_text">Select a region from the picture</span>
            <div class="error"></div>
            <div class="tags"></div>
            <div class="input_box">
                <input type="text" name="tags" class="input_textbox">
                <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="x1" id="x1" value="-">
            <input type="hidden" name="y1" id="y1" value="-">
            <input type="hidden" name="x2" id="x2" value="-">
            <input type="hidden" name="y2" id="y2" value="-">
            <input type="hidden" name="w" id="w" value="-">
            <input type="hidden" name="h" id="h" value="-">

            <div class="footer_btn">
                <p><button class="btn_success">Confirm Selection</button>
                <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;

    $('#x1').val(selection.x1);
    $('#y1').val(selection.y1);
    $('#x2').val(selection.x2);
    $('#y2').val(selection.y2);
    $('#w').val(selection.width);
    $('#h').val(selection.height);
    $('.img_error').removeClass("error");
}

$(function() {
    $('#img01').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200,
        onSelectChange: preview
    });
});

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("imgside");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onclick =function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal 
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
 span.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
 }
```

In the first image below is the modal with the image and bounding box:

[image]

The next image shows when the modal is closed and the grey scale from the bounding box remains

[image]

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a mirror of the docs](http://www.imprimerie-pau.com/Upload-Ajax-ABCI/Javascript/jquery.imgareaselect-10-0-rc-1/imgAreaSelect_Documentation.html) (main site [is bust](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)), and I noticed the `parent` option.  I guessed this could be relevant, since your modal is a block element which is hidden/displayed, unlike the default parent which is `body`.

So I added that:

```
$('#img01').imgAreaSelect({
    handles: true,
    fadeSpeed: 200,
    onSelectChange: preview,
    parent: $('#myModal')
});
```

And it works - [here's a working fork of your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/zkeawtr3/).

**NOTES:**

1. Your JSFiddle had only relative links to the `imgAreaSelect` sources, which of course did not work (they don't exist on https://jsfiddle.net/).  I found [the Javascript and CSS on CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/imgareaselect), and added them to my JSFiddle.
2. Your JSFiddle includes both `jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js` *and* `jquery.imgareaselect.js` - I think that might be 2 copies of the same lib, one compressed, and one not?  You should include only one!
3. You are using jQuery for selectors and event handlers, but also plain Javascript to do the same things, all mixed up with that.  There's nothing technically wrong with that, but it is IMO harder to read, understand, and work with.  Using jQuery has a cost - a large external lib to load means slower page load, slower page render, etc - so if you are going to pay that price, you may as well make use of it.  For example:

   ```
   // Plain Javascript
   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
   img.onclick = function() {
       // ....
   }

   // in jQuery
   var modal = $('#myModal');
   img.on('click', function() {
       // ...
   });
   ```

[Here's a 2nd JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/5fe6twmy/) with those changes applied.

**UPDATE**

As described in the comments, the selection is still visible if you open the image modal again ... I worked around that by:

1) using the `instance: true` option to return an instance of the plugin, `ias`;

```
// New var for the instance 
var ias;

$(function() {
    ias = $('#img01').imgAreaSelect({
        instance: true,
        // ... etc
    });
});
```

2) calling the the `cancelSelection` method on that instance, in the close handler.

```
span.on('click', function() {
    modal.css('display', "none");

    // Now we can call methods on the instance
    ias.cancelSelection();
});
```

I updated [the 2nd JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/5fe6twmy/) with this new code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It fixed my problem. Also as you suggested I made the corrections with Jquery lines

Comment: the solution u provided it works fine. I need a small help from the solution. when I close the modal, the backdrop disappears now, but when i reclick on the image , the image appears with the same box over the image. I would like to reset the box when I close the modal or when i click the cancel button

Comment: @Uviiii Hrm, I see.  I found a solution, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And your explanation was great and it really helped me a lot